# Magento : how to run cron manually in local machine?

Tags: magento, cron

I want to run the Magento cron by manually . I can remember in Drupal we can do it manually without setting the cron job in the server. Same like i want to do run the magento's cron in my local system. How i can do this??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use your browser to hit `http://yourdomain.com/cron.php` or php-cli to execute `cron.php` in the root of the application.

Comment: I tried with this. But i'm getting a simple white page!! Even the page is not running fully!!

Comment: What are you expecting to see? my cron runs manually, it just doesn't have output as the output goes to the magento logs

Comment: @Mayilarun the page won't display any output, you need to check whether the cron jobs have run to see if it has worked.

Comment: If hitting the cron.php over Apache works you have a big security problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your magento root, run

```
bin/magento cron:run
```